# Change primary key and its (foreign) references in existing table - Knex.js / Postgres

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

My Postgres DB has 2 tables, with thousands of rows each, that were initially created with the following migration:

```
exports.up = async function(knex, Promise) {
  // users
  await knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
    table.increments('id');
    table.timestamps(false, true);
    table.text('uid').notNullable().unique(),
    table.text('email').notNullable();
    table.text('password');
    table.text('first_name').notNullable();
    table.text('last_name').notNullable();
    table.text('subscription_id');
    table.boolean('is_active').notNullable().defaultTo(true);
    table.boolean('is_blocked').notNullable().defaultTo(false);
    table.enum('role', ['member', 'admin', 'test_user']).notNullable().defaultTo('member');
  });
  await knex.schema.raw('create unique index users_lower_email_index on users (lower(email))');

  // projects
  await knex.schema.createTable('projects', table => {
    table.increments('id');
    table.timestamps(false, true);
    table.text('name').notNullable();
    table.integer('user_id').notNullable().references('users.id').onDelete('cascade');
    table.text('data');
  });
};
```

I need to change the foreign key on the `projects` table so that it references the `uid` column instead from the `users` table.

The constraints on the `users` table are:
[image]

I tried the following migration but I get the error:

> migration failed with error: alter table "users" add column "uid" text - column "uid" of relation "users" already exists

My code:

```
exports.up = async function(knex, Promise) {
    await knex.schema.alterTable('users', table => {
        table.text('uid').primary('users_pkey');
    })

    await knex.schema.alterTable('projects', table => {
        table.text('user_id').notNullable().references('users.uid').onDelete('cascade').alter();
    });
};
```

I also tried `table.text('uid').primary('users_pkey').alter();` but then I get:

> migration failed with error: alter table "users" add constraint "users_pkey" primary key ("uid") - multiple primary keys for table "users" are not allowed

I will transfer all users in auth0 and I though its better if I use a `UUID` primary key for the `users` table.

Answer (score 6):

Before you can change the primary key of `users`, you need to remove the existing one, then you should be able to drop and recreate the foreign key in `projects`:

```js
exports.up = async (knex) => {
  await knex.schema.alterTable('users', (table) => {
    table.dropPrimary()
    table.primary('uid')
  })

  await knex.schema.alterTable('projects', (table) => {
    table.dropForeign('user_id')
    table.foreign('user_id').references('users.uid').onDelete('cascade')
  })
}
```